# How to Calculate LCM in an array or Multiple integers with Euclid Algorithm?

Tags: javascript

I have this assignment of euclid algorithm, my solution is based on [wiki hows'](http://www.wikihow.com/Find-the-Least-Common-Multiple-of-Two-Numbers#Use_Euclid.27s_Algorithm_sub) solution, I got this code which calculates LCM of 2 numbers only correctly.  I already tried other methods on wiki hows' but my logic is very wrong.

How can I apply this code to a range of numbers? base on this code like [245,244,243...45]. I have to get LCM of multiple numbers

```
function smallestCommons(arr) {
var max,
  min,
  product,
  rem;

max = Math.max.apply(Math, arr);
min = Math.min.apply(Math, arr);

  product = max*min;

 function gcd(max,min) {
 debugger;
 rem = max%min;
 max=min; // update variables until remainder is equal to 0
 min=rem;
 if(rem === 0) {
 return max; // return the max variable for GCD
  } else {
 return  gcd(max,min);
 }
 }

 return  product / gcd(max,min);
}

smallestCommons([210,45]);
```

Comment: Hint: The following property holds `lcm(a,b,c)=lcm(a,lcm(b,c))`.

Comment: what's a,b,c? and this part, (a,lcm(b,c)) is this a recursion with a as b? don't get it, I'm not good with math, is this a formula?

Comment: Yes, that's a math formula. It is true for all integers `a`, `b`, and `c`,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get LCM of multiple numbers, do recursion.
If you have three numbers 2,3,4; then take lcm of 3 and 4 and then take lcm of 2 with that. Like:

```
lcm(2,lcm(3,4))
```

Code:

```
//This is your function
function gcd(max,min){
    rem = max%min;
    max=min; // update variables until remainder is equal to 0
    min=rem;
    if(rem === 0) {
        return max; // return the max variable for GCD
    } 
    else {
        return  gcd(max,min);
    }
}

//This function computes the LCM
function lcm(a,b){
    return (a*b)/gcd(a,b)
}

//This function is the Iterator, it computes the LCM for the numbers
//in the INPUT array recursively by calling the previous function
function lcmIter(arr,len){
    //LENGTH of array -> 2 is the base case here, if there are only  
    //two numbers just compute its LCM and return it.
    if(len === 2){
        return lcm(arr[0],arr[1])
    }
    //If there are more than two numbers, compute the LCM of last 
    //number with the rest of array(now the array is one less)
    else{
        return lcm(arr[len-1],lcmIter(arr,len-1))
    }
}
//This is your input array
var array = [2,3,4,5]
//call your iterator with the array and its length
console.log(lcmIter(array,array.length))
```